# BeautifulSoup - Get text from tag even if it has other tags insise

Tags: python, string, parsing, beautifulsoup, space

Let's say that i have a following list:

```
l = [<p>NC:<strong> 1</strong></p>, <p>APC<strong> 2</strong></p>, <p>GED<strong> 3</strong></p>]
```

and type of every element in that list is bs4.element.Tag

What i want to get is a list that looks like this:

```
ll = ['NC: 1','APC: 2','GED: 3']
```

What i tried to do is something like this:

```
ll = [element.get_text() for element in l]
```

But it returns:

```
['NC:\xa01', 'APC:\xa02', 'GED:\xa03']
```

To me it looks like it has some problems with space between `<strong></strong>`. What is a way to make this right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer, the way to do it is:

```
ll = [entrance.get_text(strip=True) for entrance in l]
```